program redirects to another page, but its html is not showing up. program says 'cannot GET /page'
A newbie in Express + Nodejs here. My program is trying to redirect a user from the home page to a registration page. I added the a href attribute to one of my buttons to do that:
<div class="button1">
        <div class="icon">
         <i class="fa-solid fa-user-plus fa-xl" style="color: #ffffff; margin-right:10px;"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="button-content">
         <h3 class="buttonl"><a href="acc_id.js">Get Account ID</a></h3>
       </div>
</div>

And I also added this to my index.js file:
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("acc_id");
});

However, although the tab is  redirecting, the program is not displaying the html page inside acc_id.js. I am getting the response 'cannot GET /acc_id.js'.
here's the acc_id file too:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Responsive Registration Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
      initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/forms.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="form-title">Registration</h1>
      <form action="#">
        <div class="main-user-info">
          <div class="user-input-box">
            <label for="fullName">Full Name</label>
            <input type="text"
                    id="fullName"
                    name="fullName"
                    placeholder="Enter Full Name"/>
          </div>
          <div class="user-input-box">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    placeholder="Enter Email"/>
          </div>
          <div class="role">
            <label for="role">Are you a student or a teacher?</label>
                 <select name="Position" id="position" required>
                 <option value="student">Student</option>
                 <option value="teacher">Teacher</option>
                </select>
          </div>
          <div class="Strand">
            <label for="strand">Strand:</label>
                <select name="Strand" id="Strand" placeholder="Strand"required>
                <option value="abm">ABM</option>
                <option value="sc">ESTEM-C</option>
                <option value="se">ESTEM-E</option>
                <option value="sh">ESTEM-H</option>
                <option value="HUMSS">HUMSS</option>
                <option value="tvl">TVL</option>
                <option value="N/A">N/A (For teachers)</option>
                </select>
          </div>
          <div class="Class number">
            <label for="classnum">Class Number</label>
            <input type="number"
                    id="cnum"
                    name=""
                    placeholder="Enter Class Number"/>
          </div>
          <div class="user-input-box">
            <label for="idNumber">ID Number</label>
            <input type="Number"
                    id="idNum"
                    name="phoneNumber"
                    placeholder="Enter ID Number"/>
          </div>
          <div class="user-input-box">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password"
                    id="password"
                    name="password"
                    placeholder="Enter Password"/>
          </div>
          <div class="user-input-box">
            <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password"
                    id="confirmPassword"
                    name="confirmPassword"
                    placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-submit-btn">
          <input type="submit" value="Register">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

I have been trying to restructure the file/folder structure, like adding/removing acc_id.ejs inside the views folder, as well as adding it as a .js file inside the root, but nothing happens. I would also appreciate if someone can clarify where I should put pages that have forms to be filled by the user; based on what i read they should be in views folder, but at the same time I am confused as I have read that 'layouts' should be inside this folder, but I am not sure what exactly these layouts are.

It doesn't usually make sense to link to a .js file -- that will simply show the JS source code, not execute it. You link to .html files, and the HTML will contain <script href="acc_id.js"></script>

oh, i see. I will still be able to do operations with the data that the form will be handling, right? but through the js file?
Should the html page be inside the public folder? What about the .js, should it be in public or views folder?

I'm not really an expert on the structure of Express solutions.

This is a detailed answer to the question or the issue. A short answer is also posted.
The href needs to be given with a route path and this route path must be provided with a route handler as normally it is done.
index.html
<h3 class="buttonl"><a href="/regform">Get Account ID</a></h3>

regform route handler
server.js
app.get('/regform', (req, res) => {
  let fileName = 'reg.html';
  res.sendFile(fileName, options, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Sent:', fileName);
    }
  });
});

Please also note what is to be served from this route path is the normal html file. The reg.htm referenced in the code is an equivalent to your acc_id.js
Now regarding the directory structure, it can be plain or nested. The point is sendFile needs to have the static path, which is provided as below. In this case the directory structure is kept plain - no nesting.
server.js
var options = {
  root: path.join(__dirname, './'),
  dotfiles: 'deny',
  headers: {
    'x-timestamp': Date.now(),
    'x-sent': true,
  },
};

Just for reference, this is the root route handler.
server.js
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  let fileName = 'index.html';
  res.sendFile(fileName, options, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Sent:', fileName);
    }
  });
});

Edit : 1
server.js - complete source  code:
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

const options = {
  root: path.join(__dirname, './'),
};

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  let fileName = 'index.html';

  res.sendFile(fileName, options); // optional callback omitted
});

app.get('/regform', (req, res) => {
  let fileName = 'reg.html';

  res.sendFile(fileName, options); // optional callback omitted
});

app.listen(3000);

App's files/folders layout
app folder:
    index.js
    index.html
    reg.html
    node_modules
    package-lock.json
    package.json


hi, i tried to follow the format but I've been getting this error, ReferenceError: options is not defined. is this incorrect:
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    let fileName = 'index.html';
    const options = {
        root: path.join(__dirname, './views')
    };
    res.sendFile(fileName, options, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error!');
      } else {
        console.log('Sent!', fileName);
      }
    });
  });


hi, The given code is fine. One thing to take care in it is the declaration const options = { root: path.join(__dirname, './views'). It is now a block scoped declaration. Only available to this particular route handler. And it will not be visible to any other route handlers. Therefore an error - ReferenceError: options is not defined, will throw for all other routs. Please change the same declaration to be top level and thus take it into the global scope.  How to do it and for more, request please refer to the section "Edit 1" newly incorporated into the detailed answer.

Is the issue still persisting ?

This is a very short answer to the question or the issue. A detailed answer is also posted.
Quoted from ExpressJS documentation. For more, please refer the link below.

How do I render plain HTML? You don’t! There’s no need to “render”
HTML with the res.render() function. If you have a specific file, use the res.sendFile() function.

Rendering an HTML Template file is another programming area wherein res.render is used. However in your case it is a plain HTML, therefore sendFile would do the job. For more about Rendering HTML template, please refer to the link below.
FAQ ExpressJS
Using template engines with Express

I think what you're looking to do is serve a static file. Which as been noted already is not necessary if that static file is HTML. If you're just out there experimenting with express here is a way you can serve it up.
the file structure is something like this
/views
  -form.html
  -index.html
index.js

have in your views folder all of the html or templates you want to use and serve up static HTML as follows from your index.js
index.js


const app = express();
app.use(express.static("views"));

app.use("/form", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("views/form.html", { root: __dirname });
});

app.use("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("views/index.html", { root: __dirname });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Express server initialized");
});



your html files will be as you have listed above and your links will be defined by the first parameter in your app.use() function
this would be the snippet from your index.html
<a href="/form">Open Form</a>

